# C++ templates, efficient function for loading points

Tags: c++, templates, function, point

I would like to implement a function loading 1D/2D/3D points from file... The template parameter Point can be a 1D 2D 3D point.

```
template <typename Point>
void List <Point> ::load ( const char *file)
{

            ...

            for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < file.size(); i++ )
            {

                   if ( file[i].size() == 1 )
                    {
                            items.push_back( Point ( atof ( file[i][0].c_str() ) ) );
                    }

                    else if ( file[i].size() == 2 )
                    {
                            items.push_back( Point ( atof ( file[i][0].c_str() ), atof ( file[i][1].c_str() ) ) );
                    }

                    else if ( file[i].size() == 3 )
                    {
                            items.push_back(Point ( atof ( file[i][0].c_str() ), atof ( file[i][1].c_str() ), atof ( file[i][2].c_str() ) ) );
                    }
            }
 }
```

If I run this function for 2D point, 2D point does not have constructor with three parameters. The same situation occurs for 3D point...

```
List <Point2D> list1;
list1.load("file");  //Error
List <Point3D> list2;
list2.load("file");  //Error

Error   275 error C2661 : no overloaded function takes 3 arguments
Error   275 error C2661 : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
```

How to design such a function efficiently? The syntax is somewhat simplified, it is only an illustrative example.

Comment: Your code is not complete enough to diagnose the problem. We need to see: 1) the line that calls this load() function; 2) the definition of the Point type that the function is being instantiated with. Also, in your function you declare 'file' as a const char* parameter but then you call size() on it and file[i][0] ??

Comment: `file` is a `const char*` and you are calling `size()` on it?

Comment: @JdV It is only illustrative example....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see what your problem is: you're trying to instantiate this function with a Point class which has (only) a 1-parameter constructor, OR a Point class with a 2-parameter constructor, OR a Point class with a 3-parameter constructor. In either case, you get a compiler error about the number of parameters.

In fact, you can only instantiate this function with a Point class that has a 1-parameter constructor AND a 2-parameter constructor AND a 3-parameter constructor. The reason is that the decision of which constructor to call is made **at runtime**, based on the value of file[i].size().

Think about it: what should happen if you call this function with a Point class that only has a 2-parameter constructor, but then you come across a line in the file where file[i].size() == 3? What function should the code call?

In order to get this function to work, you need to move the decision of which constructor to call from being at runtime to being at compile time. You can do this by adding an integer template parameter that specifies the dimensionality and providing specializations for 1, 2, and 3 dimensions. Something like this might work:

```
template <typename Point, int N>
Point construct_point(const vector<string>& line);

template <typename Point>
Point construct_point<Point, 1>(const vector<string>& line)
{
    assert(line.size() == 1);
    return Point(atof ( line[0].c_str() ));
}

template <typename Point>
Point construct_point<Point, 2>(const vector<string>& line)
{
    assert(line.size() == 2);
    return Point(atof ( line[0].c_str() ), atof ( line[1].c_str() ));
}

template <typename Point>
Point construct_point<Point, 3>(const vector<string>& line)
{
    assert(line.size() == 3);
    return Point(atof ( line[0].c_str() ), atof ( line[1].c_str() ), atof ( line[2].c_str() ));
}

template <typename Point>
void List<Point>::load (const char *file)
{
    ...

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
    {
         // Assume each Point class declares a static constant integer named 'dimension'
         // which is its dimension.
         items.push_back(construct_point<Point, Point::dimension>(lines[i]));
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: @HC I was thinking about such solution... Thanks for inspiration, I find it nice...

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to implement an operator>> in your point classes.

```
class Point2D {
    int x,y;
public:
    friend istream &operator>> (istream &input, Point2D &pt) {
        return input >> pt.x >> pt.y;
    }
};

class Point3D {
    int x,y,z;
public:
    friend istream &operator>> (istream &input, Point3D &pt) {
        return input >> pt.x >> pt.y >> pt.z;
    }
};
```

Then, you could read points from an ifstream like this:

```
ifstream input("/tmp/points");
Point2D point2;
Point3D point3;
input >> point2 >> point3;
```

Comment: Nice solution. The disadvantage of doing it this way is that it couples the representation of the points in the file (e.g. space-separated) with the Point classes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry too much about efficiency when dealing with streams.  The bottleneck is generally going to be reading and writing with them, not in any processing you do before/after.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the number of dimensions of the point as a template parameter to the function, and then call `list.load<2>("file")`. And then you can specialize the functions to handle each case... but as someone pointed out, you shouldn't worry too much about efficiency.